# How do I unmark a "failed" md device?

Tags: disk, raid, mdadm

In an effort to clean up from a software bug in md, I marked half of a RAID (/dev/sda1 and /dev/sdb1 in RAID1) as faulty using:

```
mdadm /dev/md2 --fail /dev/sdb1
mdadm /dev/md2 --remove /dev/sdb1
```

But now I want to use the "failed" half instead. i.e. instead of using `/dev/sda1`, I want to use `/dev/sdb1`, but mdadm refuses to bring it online:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md2
mdadm -A /dev/md2 /dev/sdb1 --run --force
```

This fails, as it considers `/dev/sdb1` a "spare" and not an actual member of the array any more.

Comment: What fails, precisely: `-A`, or `--run`? (They're separate operations and can be performed in either order, unless this is relevant to your bug recovery). What is the exact error message? What does `mdadm -D /dev/md2` show? (Expected: `spare rebuilding   /dev/sdb1`, becoming `active sync /dev/sdb1` once the rebuilding is finished.)

Comment: Any resolution for this?

Comment: @Gilles the `-A` thinks `sdb` is a spare, not a data drive, so the `--run` won't happy.

Answer (score 2):

You're using `-A` which is `--assemble`, but you should be using `-a` which is `--add`.

If I recall correctly, devices (re)added to an existing array are always added as spares, then shortly afterwards the kernel will pick up that the array is both degraded and has a spare, and then it will start re-mirroring.  You can see this with `watch cat /proc/mdstat`.

Comment: You forgot the `cat` in the `watch` command. I can't add this because edits have to be at least 6 characters...

Comment: After adding a new drive to an existing 2-drive RAID1 array, I was not seeing the new spare rebuilt in `/proc/mdstat`. Turns out you have to manually tell mdadm to expect 3 drives in the RAID1 array, at which point it will rebuild: https://superuser.com/a/533707/458816

Answer (score 2):

The entire command that should be run is one of the following assuming the array is not assembled or running (which the OP shows as not running):

**If the array is not running:**

```
mdadm --assemble /dev/md2 /dev/sdb1
```

**However if the array is running:**

```
mdadm --manage /dev/md2 -a /dev/sdb1
```

Comment: For me, mdadm would always refuse acknowledge one of my disks when I tried to assemble. I had to use `--manage ... -a` on the "failed" disk _after_ assembling it the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the simpliest way to unmark the partition would be to add it again to the array. By the way, if you need to do a test, don't remove the drive from the array. Flag it as faulty and if you reboot, it will fall back on the other partition.

```
mdadm /dev/md2 --add /dev/sdb1
```